# Get js confirm method value in asp.net 3.5 code behind button click.?

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I want to get this script value in the code behind?

```
         Dim js As [String] =
                           (vbCr & vbLf & " if(confirm('Do you want to delete?')==true)" & vbCr & vbLf & "

         document.getElementById('" & txtRespuesta.ClientID & "').value='true';"
                            & vbCr & vbLf & " else" & vbCr & vbLf & "

         document.getElementById('") + txtRespuesta.ClientID & "').value='false';" &                               vbCr & vbLf & " "

          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Key", js, True)


          If txtRespuesta.Text = "true" Then
             'Action 1
          Else
             'Action 2
          End If
```

how to capture this script value?

If i click YES = true, No=false..

Comment: 'it should not work in client script'. What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

`onClick="if(confirm('do you really want to delete this?'))

{

  delete()

}

else

{

  //donothing or whatever

}`

Also, missed the part 'should not work in the client script'. don't really know what you mean by that, but javascript is a clientside scripting language and you will need to use some sort of HttpRequest to communicate with the server.